# How will a CNAME DNS affect Google Engine

Tags: cname

I'm hosting a clients site at `client.mysite.com`, but my client want to have its own domain, like `www.clientsite.com`.

With a CNAME configuration, I'll be able to hook my client domain to the content, but... considering I'm still hosting my clients content, which domain will be finally listed on Google with contents of `client.mysite.com` contents?

- a) mysite.com
- b) clientsite.com

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

In the DNS hierarchy, the `CNAME` resource record will be attached to the `clientside.com`. A `CNAME` is simply a reference to the location of that site's `A` record. With that in mind, I believe `mysite.com` will be listed as hosting the data.

Comment: So how would this work with, suppose, a CDN hosted content. Like if I had a Heroku app (myapp.herokuapp.com), CNAME linked to my www.myapp.com DNS server. Will Google list herokuapp.com instead of myapp.com?

Answer (score 0):

Does your client want it to appear under his name?

If so, then this should not be solved using DNS (well, not only using DNS).

If your client wants to get the content listed under his domain name, the best way to do this, is to add their name to your server.

Then point client domain name to your server.

The best way to do the pointing (when also considering SEO)

is to make an webforward (301 permanent) from the root, to the www 
and make the www subdomain point to the ressource.
(Or vice verca)

IF you are using the example above (webforward on root) you can use a cname instead of an A record to point the domain name. However **do not** add a cname to the root of a domain (effectively shutting down your domain name).

So-

**Short Answer:** 
client.mysite.com will have the content (also according to google).

Any attempt to obfuscate this is black hat or grey hat ;)

a better way of doing it is to simply setup the clients domain name on your server.
Then point **only one hostname** to the server. Server host/headers will take care of the rest.

**Setup in DNS**

@ webforward 301 www
www a or Cname to server

Quick rules:
NEVER put Cname on the root of a domain
Only allow 1 hostname to show content (can be done both as explained above via DNS/webforward or via server configurations)